# Rails Edit Class form Not Saving to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have the following form that will be used by admins to edit instances of the "exchange" class:

```
<%= form_for(@exchange) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :status %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :status, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :status_1 %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :status_1, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :status_2 %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :status_2, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Submit Changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This form is being rendered on **exchanges/edit.html.erb**

I have the following controller actions:

```
def edit

    @exchange = Exchange.find(params[:id])

end

def update
    @exchange = Exchange.find(params[:id])
    @exchange.update(exchange_params)
    respond_with @exchange
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
resources :exchanges do
    patch :update_ordid, on: :member
    patch :update_ordlnk, on: :member
    post :mark_arrival, on: :member
    post :close_exchange, on: :member
end
```

I know the "update" controller action is being called successfully, because after clicking the submit button I am being redirected to the view page for the exchange in question. The issue is that the record for that exchange in the DB is not being updated.

Comment: Can you post your `exchange_params` and `routes.rb`?

Comment: Added my routes.rb, wouldn't exchange_params just be the parameters listed in the form?

Comment: Nope, with Rails 4 and strong parameters you have to define which parameters you want to accept. I will post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to whitelist the parameters in your controller as a private method.

```
private

def exchange_params
  params.require(:exchange).permit(:status, :status_1, :status_2)
end
```

With the above, I am *assuming* that your model `Exchange` has a table in the database, `exchanges` and that table has the columns `status`, `status_1`, `status_2`.

you can read more [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: Thanks! Your assumptions were correct and it is now working as intended.